# Can't run react-native project in a physical device instead of emulator?

Tags: android-studio, react-native, build

I installed Android Studio and also I have an emulator in AS.
I started new react native project and I running successfully on emulator.
This process was successful.

**But**

I just connected my new device to Android Studio and selected Deployment target also

But I don't know what to do next. But from my knowledge I tried to `react-native run-android` in my terminal, but it shows

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not install the app on
>   the device, read the error above for details. Make sure you have an
>   Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your
>   Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

So can't run the project in device.
Please help me to do next steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable Debugging over USB 
   Most Android devices can only install and run apps downloaded from Google Play, by default. You will need to enable USB Debugging on your device in order to install your app during development.

   To enable USB debugging on your device, you will first need to enable the "Developer options" menu by going to Settings → About phone and then tapping the Build number row at the bottom seven times. You can then go back to Settings → Developer options to enable "USB debugging".
2. Plug in your device via USB 
   Let's now set up an Android device to run our React Native projects. Go ahead and plug in your device via USB to your development machine.

   Now check that your device is properly connecting to ADB, the Android Debug Bridge, by running adb devices.

   `$ adb devices`
   List of devices attached
   emulator-5554 offline   # Google emulator
   14ed2fcc device         # Physical device
   Seeing device in the right column means the device is connected. You must have only one device connected at a time.
3. Run your app 
   Type the following in your command prompt to install and launch your app on the device:

   `$ react-native run-android`
   If you get a "bridge configuration isn't available" error, see Using adb reverse.
   Hint
   You can also use the React Native CLI to generate and run a Release build (e.g. react-native run-android --variant=release).

> Make sure to shutdown the emulator and only have one device connected.

Read further here :- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Comment: where do i find $ adb devices @kabangi julius

Comment: On terminal type `adb list` should list all commands available. It get's installed when you install android studio

Comment: You must have only one device connected at a time. - this clue is more then enough for me dude i connected two device at the same time. but the thing is after build the app something is not working and in some devices app getting crashed.. @kabangi julius

Comment: Make sure to shutdown the emulator and only have one device connected. Then check android monitor  and select the device look out for the logs, you might get the origin of the error

Comment: If it does work for you please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to run tcp command in platform-tools in command line for connecting your mobile.